# $25$ colored dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

$25$ colored dice are thrown and their results are put at random at a square matrix $5\times 5$. Dice colors are as follows: $5$ Red, $5$ Blue, $5$ Yellow, $5$ Green and $5$ Orange.

[image: 25 colored dice]

I am interested in calculating the following probabilities:

1. The probability that a bar of length $3$ ($3$ consecutive dice of the same color),    vertical or horizontal, appears somewhere in the grid.
2. The probability that a bar of length $4$ ($4$ consecutive dice of the same color),    vertical or horizontal, appears somewhere in the grid.
3. The probability that a bar of length $5$ ($5$ consecutive dice of the same color),    vertical or horizontal, appears somewhere in the grid.

Comment: Does the result of the dice throw matter at all?

Comment: This is likely to end up as a huge exercise in inclusion-exclusion that can only be worked out by computer -- would you be interested in such a solution?

Comment: Answering to Arthur, actually no. Each dice has one color at all faces. Probably a better description of the experiment can be given, but even in this state I think is enough clear.

Comment: In that case, "dice", "thrown" and "results" are misleading. The question should read something like "25 coloured cubes are randomly arranged in a square $5\times5$ matrix, with all arrangements equally probable. ..." (And no, it's not clear enough, it's quite hard to understand because of all the misleading cues.)

Comment: I agree, sounds better. Should I edit it now? I am more concerned about the solution and your previous question. What I would like to see, is a sketch of the solution. Surely involves inclusion-exclusion and I think can be formulated without the use of a computer.

Comment: It can certainly be *formulated* without the use of a computer. The question is whether you're interested in a solution if actually carrying it out, not just formulating it in principle, would require a computer.

Comment: If carrying out to compute the probabilities, yes would require the use of a computer.

Comment: maybe the third problem is easier to answer?

Answer (score 1):

The third question can be solved without a computer.

We have one condition for each row and one for each column. Multiple conditions can only be satisfied simultaneously if they correspond to the same direction.

The probablity for $k$ particular compatible conditions to be satisfied simultaneously is $\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{5-j}{\binom{25-5j}5}$.

Thus, by inclusion–exclusion the probability for at least one of the conditions to be satisfied is

$$
10\cdot\frac5{\binom{25}5}-2\cdot\binom52\cdot\frac{5\cdot4}{\binom{25}5\binom{20}5}+2\cdot\binom53\cdot\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{\binom{25}5\binom{20}5\binom{15}5}
\\
-2\cdot\binom54\cdot\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{\binom{25}5\binom{20}5\binom{15}5\binom{10}5}+2\cdot\binom55\cdot\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{\binom{25}5\binom{20}5\binom{15}5\binom{10}5\binom55}
\\
=\frac5{5313}-\frac5{10296594}+\frac5{10306890594}-\frac5{2597336429688}+\frac1{2597336429688}
\\[15pt]
=\frac{32145551}{34175479338}\approx9.406\cdot10^{-4}\;.
$$

Since it's highly unlikely that more than one condition is satisfied, this probability is very well approximated by the expected number of satisfied conditions,

$$
10\cdot\frac5{\binom{25}5}=\frac5{5313}\approx9.411\cdot10^{-4}\;.
$$